# How can a REST client discover acceptable media types?

Tags: rest, http

If a client sends HTTP POST to some URL and it returns HTTP 415 ("Unsupported Media Type") how is the client supposed to look up the list of acceptable media types?

When a client requests an invalid method, HTTP 405 must return a list of acceptable values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

When a client requests an invalid media type, HTTP 415 does not return the list of acceptable values.

If nothing else, I want my client to print out a helpful debug message stating that I requested X but the server was expecting Y.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using an open.api document then you should be able to use that.

Comment: @JimmyShoe I am looking for an answer that references the HTTP specification as opposed to some specific implementation, but thank you for the consideration.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept from the client with https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17 response by the server, but you usually want to make that part of the preflight OPTIONS call, _not_ the POST call, because obviously by the time you're making the POST call it's already too late.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Can you please post an answer containing a sample request/response showing `OPTIONS` returning acceptable `Content-Type` values for a `POST`?